# Installing Python package PATH error

Tags: python

I used this prompt in Windows Powershell `py -m pip install pandas`.
I got back this message saying it was installed but not the proper PATH. Does anyone know what this means and is this going to be a problem if I try and use `import pandas as pd` in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: So basically you installed f2py.exe in a location that is not listed in the PATH variable. So you can decide to install it elsewhere or just add the location to the PATH variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve? The message in the screenshot isn’t necessarily anything you must address as it’s only a warning